# Android Null point exception when handling to close a dialog box using image button

Tags: android, dialog, nullpointerexception

I have a `Dialog` which I want to manage to close it using `ImageButton`, 
I tried to use `dismiss()` and `cancel()` methods, but they weren`t exist in the methods which appeared, so what I tried was the code below:

```
buttonDialogClose = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.buttonCloseDialog);
    buttonDialogClose.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            finish();  
        }
    });
```

But unfortunately it shows an Exception which is:

```
11-09 11:44:25.696: E/AndroidRuntime(649): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-09 11:44:25.696: E/AndroidRuntime(649): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.lavan/com.example.lavan.LavanMainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-09 11:44:25.696: E/AndroidRuntime(649):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
11-09 11:44:25.696: E/AndroidRuntime(649):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
11-09 11:44:25.696: E/AndroidRuntime(649):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
11-09 11:44:25.696: E/AndroidRuntime(649):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
11-09 11:44:25.696: E/AndroidRuntime(649):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-09 11:44:25.696: E/AndroidRuntime(649):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-09 11:44:25.696: E/AndroidRuntime(649):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
11-09 11:44:25.696: E/AndroidRuntime(649):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-09 11:44:25.696: E/AndroidRuntime(649):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-09 11:44:25.696: E/AndroidRuntime(649):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
11-09 11:44:25.696: E/AndroidRuntime(649):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
11-09 11:44:25.696: E/AndroidRuntime(649):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-09 11:44:25.696: E/AndroidRuntime(649): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-09 11:44:25.696: E/AndroidRuntime(649):  at com.example.lavan.LavanMainActivity.onCreate(LavanMainActivity.java:92)
11-09 11:44:25.696: E/AndroidRuntime(649):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
11-09 11:44:25.696: E/AndroidRuntime(649):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
11-09 11:44:25.696: E/AndroidRuntime(649):  ... 11 more
```

this is my `Dialog` code:

```
tv5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvSearchSD);
    tv5.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Dialog dialog = new Dialog(LavanMainActivity.this);
            dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.search_dialog_layout);
            dialog.show();

        }
    });
```

is anybody explain why it is for and how can I solve it, thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: use `(ImageButton)current_dialog_view. findViewById(R.id.buttonCloseDialog);` if ImageVIew is inside Dialog Layout

Comment: Can you show me your code related to dialog instead of imageButton?

Comment: diloag code is needed..

Comment: @kalyanpvs I edited my question with dialog code

Comment: @edisonthk I edited my question with dialog code

Comment: @amalBit I edited my code with the full log

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK as I`m really new to programming ,I didn`t get the hint in your answer, could you please explain more what and where should I exactly do what you suggest, thanks a lot

Comment: post your onCreate() method or else if possible post entire Activity. then definitely u will get help from Stackoverflow...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your buttonDialogClose should be initialized with the Dialog. In your case.

```
tv5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvSearchSD);
    tv5.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Dialog dialog = new Dialog(LavanMainActivity.this);
            dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.search_dialog_layout);
            Button buttonDialogClose = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.buttonDialogClose);
            buttonDialogClose .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onClick(View v) {
              dialog.dismiss();
          }
            });
            dialog.show();

        }
    });
```

Comment: THANK YOU ,THANK YOU and thank you, now it works perfectly without any error :)

Comment: Upvoat if it helped ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use AlertDialog instead of Dialog. Here's sample code of alertDialog.

```
private class myCustomAlertDialog extends AlertDialog {

    protected myCustomAlertDialog(Context context) {
        super(context);

        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.search_dialog_layout, null);
        ImageButton buttonDialogClose = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.buttonCloseDialog);
        setView(view);
        buttonDialogClose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // I want the dialog to close at this point
                dismiss();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Instance it and show it by

```
new myCustomAlertDialog(LavanMainActivity.this).show();
```